# Why does the equation of a wave contain the term $\omega t$ instead of $vt$ in the wave equation $y=A\sin (kx-\omega t)$?

Tags: waves, kinematics, frequency, dimensional-analysis, wavelength

Why does the equation of a wave contain the term $\omega t$ instead of $vt$ in the wave equation
$$y=A\sin (kx-\omega t).$$

I think of the constant $k$ which for higher values increases the frequency $f$ of the wave (decreases the wavelength $\lambda$ of the wave) or vice versa when $k$ decreases.

And the graph shifts to the right when a constant is subtracted from the variable. For example the $\sin x$ graph shifts to the right by $d$ units in the graph $\sin (x-d)$

So say the wave travels a distance $d$ in the time interval $t$ with a velocity $v$, shouldn't the distance travelled by the wave be $d=vt$. And therefore as each second passes the graph as a whole moves a certain distance $d$ which can be modeled as
$$y=A\sin (kx-d)=A\sin (kx-vt)$$

So how does the angular velocity $\omega$ come in picture?

Comment: $\sin(kx-\omega t)=\sin(k(x-(\omega/k)t)= \sin(k(x-vt))$ with $v=\omega/k$.

Comment: $kx-d$ doesn't make sense, because it is dimensionally inconsistent (angle - length).

Answer (score 6):

You have to have a dimensionally consistent equation.

Yes, you can have $y = A \sin (x-d)$ and then get $y = A \sin (x-vt)$ with $d = vt$ but what you cannot do is suddenly introduce a factor $k$ for one term and not the other, ie $y\ne A \sin (kx-vt)$.

What you can do is start with $y = A \sin (x-vt)$ and then introduce the wave number $k$ in both terms which results in $y = A \sin (kx'-kvt') \Rightarrow  y = A \sin (kx'-\omega t')$ as $v=\omega/k$

Answer (score 3):

This supplements some of the other answers and comments given earlier.

Given $y=A\sin\theta$, we must have $\theta$ with units of radians, often considered dimensionless.

Given $y=A\sin(x-d)$, we must have $(x-d)$ dimensionless. 
Here, $x$ cannot be a length.
*(Argument: if you write the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x-d)$, the terms must all have the same units as $\sin(x-d)$ [which is dimensionless].)*

Thus one can have $y=A\sin(k(x-d))$ only if $k(x-d)$ is dimensionless.
So, if $x$ is a length, then $k$ must have the units of an inverse-length... indeed, $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength.

For physics, we would have form $y=A\sin( k(x-vt) )$, where $t$ is a time on a clock and $v$ has units of velocity.

If one introduces $\omega =\frac{2\pi}{T}$, where $T$ is the wave-period,
one could have written the argument more symmetrically as
$y=A\sin( kx-\omega t)$, with $\omega=kv$.

Comment: The value of $k$ could be $1$ with a unit of reciprocal length and this makes $y=A\sin (x-d)$ a valid solution with the term in the bracket dimensionless.

Comment: @Farcher I prefer to write standard physics equations in a form that is independent of the system of units used.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the equation of a wave contain the term $\omega t$ instead of $vt$.
> in the wave equation
> $$y=A\sin (kx-\omega t).$$

The argument of the sine function always needs to be
an angle, i.e. a dimensionless quantiy.
Usually we call this angle the phase ($\phi$).

The wave number $k$ is defined to be the phase difference per *length*
$$k=\frac{\Delta\phi}{\Delta x}$$
and likewise the angular velocity $\omega$ is defined as the phase difference per *time*
$$\omega=\frac{\Delta\phi}{\Delta t}.$$

Hence the expression
$$\phi = kx-\omega t \tag{1}$$
is the phase at a certain position $x$ and time $t$.
And that is why this phase $\phi$ is put into $\sin(...)$ as the argument.
On the other hand: An expression like $\phi = kx-vt$ would not make
sense, because it is an inconstent mix of a dimensionless quantity
($kx$) and a length ($vt$).

If you want to write it using the wave speed $v$ instead of $\omega$,
then you can certainly do this. Just use $v=\frac{\omega}{k}$ or $\omega =kv$ and rewrite (1):
$$\phi = kx-\omega t = kx-kv t = k(x-vt) \tag{2}$$
Here you see it more clearly that the wave fronts (i.e. the places
of constant phase $\phi$) actually move with speed $v$ to the right.